How to add values of one dataframe to another, double-conditioned by the receiving dataframe?
I am trying to merge two dataframes in quite a specific way. They are each similar to these two:
df1 <- data.frame(Countries = c("Portugal", "Andorra", "Spain", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain"),
                 Year_of_order = c("2015", "2016", "2014", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015"),
                 Type_of_order = c("vegetables", "meat", "fruits", "fruits", "meat", "vegetable", "meat")
)

df2 <- data.frame(Names = c("Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain"),
                 Year = c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2016"),
                 Budget_spent = c("452", "444", "429", "456", "854", "876", "833", "102", "104", "96")
)

The second dataframe is the product of a pivot_longer , that is why it looks a bit weird.
What I want is to add a new column to df1, called Budget_spent :  its values should be those indicated in df2 for the corresponding Year and Names. Basically, when df1 both Year_of_order and Countries match df2's Year and Names , I want to have the value of df2's Budget_spent. To my understanding, I would need to do a double-conditioned match, but maybe I'm wrong.
In case my poor explanation was not clear, here's what I would like the output to look like:
>df1
   Countries  Year_of_order  Type_of_order  Budget_spent
1  Portugal   2015           vegetables     876
2  Andorra    2016           meat           429
3  Spain      2014           fruits         102
4  Portugal   2016           fruits         833
5  Portugal   2014           meat           854
6  Portugal   2015           vegetable      876
7  Spain      2015           meat           104

I tried quite a lot of things (match, merge, if, when , for row), with little success, mostly because I can't even grasp conceptually what process should I apply:
#Here's the most complete attempt, the rest look quite torn apart

df1$Budget_spent <- for (row in df1$Countries) {
  match(df1$Countries, df2$Names)+
  match(df1$Year_of_order, df2$Year)+
  df2$Budget_spent}

#Error message: argument non-numeric for binary operator

I would be very grateful of any help or indication on how to address the issue.

Am sure this is a duplicate question, but could not find a suitable duplicate. If anyone reading this finds a suitable duplicate please simply close/vote to close

Use left-join from dplyr:
library(tidyverse)
left_join(df1, df2, join_by(Countries == Names, Year_of_order == Year))

  Countries Year_of_order Type_of_order Budget_spent
1  Portugal          2015    vegetables          876
2   Andorra          2016          meat          429
3     Spain          2014        fruits          102
4  Portugal          2016        fruits          833
5  Portugal          2014          meat          854
6  Portugal          2015     vegetable          876
7     Spain          2015          meat          104


Thank you, it worked perfectly (even added automatic NAs to missing values)!

You can merge on multiple columns w/o extra packages.
> merge(df1, df2, by.x=c('Countries', 'Year_of_order'), by.y=c('Names', 'Year'))
  Countries Year_of_order Type_of_order Budget_spent
1   Andorra          2016          meat          429
2  Portugal          2014          meat          854
3  Portugal          2015    vegetables          876
4  Portugal          2015     vegetable          876
5  Portugal          2016        fruits          833
6     Spain          2014        fruits          102
7     Spain          2015          meat          104

